# How do I add project references to a wix project programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, wix

I am attempting to add references to a Wix project after it has been created programmatically. This is in an implementation of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard`. I know how to do it for `EnvDTE.Project`'s:

```
// Add project reference for projectA from projectB.
// Allows projectA to use classes from projectB.
var temp = (VSProject2)projectA.Object;
temp.References.AddProject(projectB);
```

But I can't figure out how to do it for an `OAWixProject`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I should mention that problems arise when I attempt the cast `(VSProject2)projectA.Object` when `projectA` is an `OAWixProject`.

Comment: What assembly are you referencing to create the WIX project?

Comment: The WIX project gets created via an existing .wixproj template, it doesn't get created from scratch programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how you'd use WIX sdk dlls to edit the wixproj file, but you could always resort to editing the wixproj xml programatically. Looks like you'd add an ItemGroup element to the root Project element. The xml you'd need to inject would look something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MySolution\CustomAssembly.csproj">
        <Name>CustomAssembly</Name>
        <Project>{233e4372-895b-4c8d-99b0-f8314d907d66}</Project>
        <Private>True</Private>
        <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
        <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
        <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The project guid is taken from the csproj of the referenced project.

Comment: I think this will work. You can safely remove a project, edit, and re-add a project to a solution after the project has been created. I will try this and report back on how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was asked some time ago and the anwer might not be of any relevance for you anymore, I came up with the following solution:

Assuming you have a `EnvDTE.Project` representing a WiX project and you want to add a reference to another `EnvDTE.Project`, there is no need to cast to or work with the `OAWixProject` type:

```
void AddProjectReference(
    EnvDTE.Project wixProject,
    EnvDTE.Project projectToReference)
{
    var references = wixProject.ProjectItems
        .Cast<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>()
        .Select(x => x.Object)
        .OfType<VSLangProj.References>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (references != null)
    {
        references.AddProject(projectToReference);
    }
}
```

So the difference to working with a `VSProject` is how the references instance is retrieved (using `VSProject.References` for `VSProject` as you mentioned).